# How to fix this FileNotFound in Spyder to find and read my files?

Tags: python, spyder

```
# READING FILES

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\MakeB\\2022-02-21\\Absorbance')
for f in sorted(os.listdir(), key=lambda f: f[-9:]):
filenumber = len(os.listdir())
if f[-4:] == '.txt':
    df = pd.read_table(f, sep = '\s+', skiprows= 14, header = None)
    df.columns = ["X","Y"]        
    tdf = df.truncate(before = 161, after = 725)
    tdf.columns = ["X","Y"]
    x = tdf["X"]
    y = tdf["Y"]
```

What can i do to fix this error code?

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\MakeB\2022-02-21\Absorbance'

Comment: ```What can i do to fix this error code?``` Create that directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use forward slashes in the path:

```
os.chdir('c:/Users/MakeB/2022-02-21/Absorbance')
```

or use a raw string:

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\MakeB\2022-02-21\Absorbance')
```

Comment: it still outputting FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/MakeB/2022-02-21/Absorbance'

Comment: What happens if you put in another directory like `C:/`?  Are you 100% confident the directory exists locally or could it be on a networked drive or the like?

Comment: Another sanity check would be to run `os.getcwd()` to see where you actually are.

Comment: IPdb [5]: os.getcwd()
'/Users/MakeB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/app'  is what I got back as to where i am. How do i Make sure it finds the file I want?

Comment: Ok.  Does changing to '/Users/MakeB' work?  It still seems like there is a problem with the directory you're trying to change into.  Do you have unusually strict directory permissions set in Windows or anything?

Comment: I use a mac im not sure if Iit even asked for permissions or how to go about doing that

Comment: From the path you have in the question `'C:\\Users\\MakeB\\2022-02-21\\Absorbance'`, it seems like you're trying to find a directory in Windows/on a PC.  That may be the issue.  Did changing the directory using `os.chdir('users/MakeB')` work?  Switch to a terminal and try to `cd` into that directory and make sure it has a 2022-02-21 subdirectory with a Absorbance directory inside of that (or look via the Finder).